# Detaching from ptrace called on itself

Tags: c, linux

On linux an easy method to check whether the program is in a debugger is to check `if(ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0) == -1)`. How can I detach after this? `ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, 0, 0, 0)` does not work (returns `-1`).

Comment: I don't think you can. You should not trust `ptrace` to return if you are actually being debugged, such a test can be circumvented easily.

Answer (score 0):

Only the "parent" (debugger) can detach from the traced child process; it is impossible for the child to get itself detached. [`man ptrace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html):

```
       PTRACE_TRACEME
              Indicate that this process is to be traced by its parent. …

              The PTRACE_TRACEME request is used only by the tracee; the
              remaining requests are used only by the tracer. …
```